# How does this getter variable with async works in DART

Tags: dart, async-await, getter

I came across these code in flutter.

```dart
    static Future<String> get platformVersion async
    {
        final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
        return version;
    }
```

I was creating flutter plugin using android studio.
Do we have to use await keyword while accessing its value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because the return type is a Future, you `await` the value. You would do :

```
String platformVersion = await GetVersion.platformVersion;
```