# Can getters be used on functions in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to create a  Class like so to create more easily my different `flutter_google` maps markers

```dart
class MapMarkers {
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> get markerStrawberry =>
      Assets.images.images.focus.strawberry
          .toBitmapDescriptor();
}

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> get markerCheese =>
      Assets.images.images.focus.cheese
          .toBitmapDescriptor();
}



extension AssetToBitmap on AssetGenImage {
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> toBitmapDescriptor() =>
      BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          const ImageConfiguration(size: Size(24, 24)), path);
}
```

as you can see `BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage` is a function that needs `awaiting` am I allowed to call it through a getter or do I need to create methods instead inside my `MapMarkers Class` ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598832/how-does-this-getter-variable-with-async-works-in-dart) answer your question?

Comment: yes thank you - is this code from the flutter SDK ? *should I delete my question thanks*

Comment: I've added async to my getter as seen in your link, thank you so much @PeterKoltai

Comment: You are welcome. This is a similar question, if the answer there helps you, you might consider upvoting that answer. It is up to you what you do with your question. I will vote to close this as duplicate. You will see an automatic comment below.